# How to get the maximum rate (frequency) at which a slider can be moved?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I want to determine the rate (frequency) at which a slider can be moved in a MFC based Visual C++ program (using Visual Studio 2012).  So how do I get the appropriate polling rate programmatically?

Here is the code I use for capturing the slider value:

```
void CMainDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
// catches slider horizontal scrolling events
{
    double val;
    ScopeGuardMutex guard(&m_mutex);
    val = (double)(((CSliderCtrl *)pScrollBar)->GetPos()) / (double)SLD_MAX;
    rec->param = val;
    CDialog::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

If this value cannot be determined programmatically then is there an approximate value e.g. 100Hz?

Comment: It may be helpful to include more information about what you have tried to show research of the problem. Code snippets are always a plus.

Comment: This question is the result of a misunderstanding that lead to an inappropriate design. The speed at which you can update the slider is entirely up to how fast your program calls `GetMessage` (see [Paint messages will come in as fast as you let them](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111219-00/?p=8863/) for details). The solution: Don't poll. Let the slider inform your application when it needs to update. The Windows GUI is event-based. Polling is usually wrong here.

Comment: I don't want to poll, I want to know what is the approximate rate at which the messages will arrive.  Is it 100Hz or 1000Hz?

Comment: Messages will arrive no faster than your application calls `GetMessage`. As the link above explains, this limit is not a feature of the Slider Control. Why do you need to know the max. frequency? What are you going to do with this information?

Comment: I want to take the value of the slider and slew rate limit it, to avoid sudden changes!

Comment: Why do you need to know the max. change rate ahead of time then? Can you not work off the observed information? You can query the current message's timestamp by calling [GetMessageTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644939.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised that I was not approaching this problem in the right way.  The rate at which the slider value is changed is not important, rather what is important is the rate at which the slider value is followed.  The two rates are independent.  Assuming the parameter being controlled by the slider is in the range 0 to 1, the rate at which the slider value is followed (r) and the maximum frequency (f) at which the value is allowed to change are what should be used in a slew rate limiter to calculate the maximum step size (s), as follows:

```
s = 2 * f / r
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to poll slider. The Windows GUI is event-based by design.

Just handle the `OnHScroll()` or `OnVScroll()` message as described in Slider notification messages. When the user moves the slider and releases the mouse button, a `TB_THUMBPOSITION` notification is send (`nSBCode` parameter of the scroll handler). The position is passed in the `nPos` parameter and a pointer to the slider control in the `pScrollBar` parameter (this must be casted to `CSliderCtrl*`).

Add the `WM_HSCROLL` handler like this:

```
void CMyDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    if (IDC_SLIDER == pScrollBar->GetDlgCtrlID())
    {
        // When there is no member variable and we need to access the control
        CSliderCtrl* pSlider = reinterpret_cast<CSliderCtrl*>(pScrollBar);
        // Handle event here
        switch (nSBCode)
        {
            case TB_LINEUP:
            case TB_LINEDOWN:
            case TB_PAGEUP:
            case TB_PAGEDOWN:
            case TB_THUMBPOSITION:
            case TB_TOP:
            case TB_BOTTOM:
            case TB_THUMBTRACK:
            case TB_ENDTRACK:
            default:
                break;
        }
        return;
    }
    // Default handling if not a slider control.
    CDialog::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

Comment: I already use OnHScroll in my program.  I want to know what is the rate (in Hz) on a system at which these messages will arrive.

Comment: The message pump processing speed depends on many things. Read the MSDN article suggested by IInspectable to find out more.